# Circular dependency in pandas dataframe 2

Tags: python, pandas

This is a continuation of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30957367/circular-dependency-in-pandas-dataframe).

I'm trying to write a small script to calculate the result of a game and I'd like to know if this is possible to do using vectors or if I will have to use a for loop to iterate through the list.

The idea is you start with start_bal (£100) and buy tokens, each token costing tok_cost (£10). You then win or lose £1 for each token depending on the outcome (a['Results']). So I should be able to buy 10 tokens at £10 per token on the first game and since the result is a win, the Balance should go up to £110, meaning I can now buy 11 tokens at £10 per token for the second game, and so on.

This is the basic code. I tried different ways of calculating the a['Bal'] column but I can't seem to get it so I've just left it blank, hopefully someone can help:

```
import pandas

start_bal = 100.0 #start off with £100
tok_cost = 10

#create an empty data frame.
a = pandas.DataFrame()

#create a list of results, 1 is win, -1 is lose
a['Result'] = [1,1,1,-1,-1]

#calculate your bankroll after each game
a['Bal'] = ...
```

Comment: do you really need a pandas df for this?

Comment: @EdChum -- I added a link to the prior question.  The solution to the original problem uses `cumprod` so it's not a bad application for pandas although it's certainly possible to solve without pandas

Comment: How is this really different from the prior question?  Aren't you just essentially making the risk 10% (vs 5% in the original question)?

Comment: Hi John, the idea is that I want token cost to change over time, so it won't always be 10%. So at each row in the list the number of tokens bought will be the balance at that row divided by the cost of the token at that row. I didn't want to confuse matters by adding this in at this point. I merely want to know if it's doable with a simple line as in my first question (the 5% risk).