# Calculating a running total column minus X % values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need help with a running total in python.

I have a DF with a starting value of 100 and i have a column of % values that need to be deducted from the previous value keeping a running total.

Im relatively new to python and i have only been able to do this so far by iterating over the rows (which im trying to avoid) and i just cant get the logic to work when vectorising it. It always seems to loop back around and reference itself.

Any help would be much appreciated

```
df = df[['trade_long','close_long','active_trade','take_profit']]

df['current_trade_size'] = 0 
df.loc[df['trade_long'], 'current_trade_size'] = 100
df.loc[df['close_long'], 'current_trade_size'] = 0
df['trade_ramainder'] = (1 - (df['take_profit']/100))
df['previous_trade_size'] = df['current_trade_size'].shift(1)
df['current_trade_size'] =  df['previous_trade_size'] * df['trade_ramainder']

CURRENT OUTPUT 
            
| Date     | trade_long | close_long | active_trade | take_profit | current_trade_size | trade_ramainder | previous_trade_size |        
|2020-01-07| True       | False      | True         | 0.00        | NaN                |  1.00           | NaN                 |
|2020-01-08| False      | False      | True         | 0.00        | 100.00             | 1.00            | 100.0.              |
|2020-01-09| False      | False      | True         | 0.68        | 0.00               | 0.99            | 0.0                 |
|2020-01-10| True       | False      | True         | 0.00        | 0.00               | 1.00            | 0.0                 |
|2020-01-11| False      | False      | True         | 0.69        | 99.30              | 0.99            | 100.0.              |
|2020-01-12| True       | False      | True         | 0.00        | 0.00               | 1.00            | 0.0                 |
|2020-01-13| False      | False      | True         | 0.00        | 100.00             | 1.00            | 100.0.              |

DESIRED OUTPUT

| Date     | trade_long | close_long | active_trade | take_profit | current_trade_size |    
|2020-01-07| True       | False      | True         | 0.00        | 100.00             |                 
|2020-01-08| False      | False      | True         | 0.00        | 100.00             |              
|2020-01-09| False      | False      | True         | 0.68        | 99.32              |               
|2020-01-10| True       | False      | True         | 0.00        | 100.00             |                 
|2020-01-11| False      | False      | True         | 0.69        | 98.63              | 
|2020-01-12| True       | False      | True         | 0.00        | 100.00             | 
|2020-01-13| False      | False      | True         | 0.00        | 100.00               |
```

Comment: Can you come up with a direct formula? One that may involve `pd.cumsum` or `pd.cumprod`, like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30957367/12846804). Otherwise, there is no vectorizing an actual circular dependency. Then at least go to Numpy, which will be faster than pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution to your problem:

```py
# == Import necessary libraries ================================================
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# == Create test dataframe =====================================================
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["2020-01-07", True, False, True, 0.00],
        ["2020-01-08", False, False, True, 0.00],
        ["2020-01-09", False, False, True, 0.68],
        ["2020-01-10", True, False, True, 0.00],
        ["2020-01-11", False, False, True, 0.69],
        ["2020-01-12", True, False, True, 0.00],
        ["2020-01-13", False, False, True, 0.00],
    ], columns = ['Date', 'trade_long','close_long','active_trade','take_profit']
).set_index("Date")

# == Solution implementation ===================================================
# Create column to store calculations and fill it with default value (in this case zero)
df['current_trade_size'] = 0

# Fill the created column based on rules
df.loc[df['trade_long'], 'current_trade_size'] = 100
df.loc[df['close_long'], 'current_trade_size'] = 0

# Applying the deduction from previous value keeping a running total.
# To do so, we'll be using NumPy function `where`. This function allows us
# to set the value for a column, based on a certain condition.
# In our case, we'll keep the value unmodified, when it equals 100.
# Otherwise, we'll consider it as being 100 minus the cumulative sum of the
# values from "take_profit" column.

df["current_trade_size"] = np.where(df["current_trade_size"] == 100, 100, 100 - df["take_profit"].cumsum())
#                                   ^-----------------------------^ ^--^  ^------------------------------^
#                                   |                               |     |
#                                   |                               |     +-- Set this value, when condition isn't met
#                                   |                               +-- Set this value, when condition is met
#                                   +-- Condition to evaluate
```

**Output:**

| Date | trade_long | close_long | active_trade | take_profit | current_trade_size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-07 | True | False | True | 0 | 100 |
| 2020-01-08 | False | False | True | 0 | 100 |
| 2020-01-09 | False | False | True | 0.68 | 99.32 |
| 2020-01-10 | True | False | True | 0 | 100 |
| 2020-01-11 | False | False | True | 0.69 | 98.63 |
| 2020-01-12 | True | False | True | 0 | 100 |
| 2020-01-13 | False | False | True | 0 | 98.63 |

### NOTES

To achieve the desired output, we use NumPy's `where` function.
Inside this function, we define that when the value from the `current_trade_size` column **is not** equal to 100, we subtract the cumulative sum from column `take_profit` from the value 100.

The code `df["take_profit"].cumsum()` calculates a cumulative sum of `take_profit` column. In other words it sums the current line's value with all previous lines values. Therefore, `df["take_profit"].cumsum()` returns the following values:

| Date | take_profit |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-07 | 0 |
| 2020-01-08 | 0 |
| 2020-01-09 | 0.68 |
| 2020-01-10 | 0.68 |
| 2020-01-11 | 1.37 |
| 2020-01-12 | 1.37 |
| 2020-01-13 | 1.37 |

These values are then subtracted from the starting value of 100

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this i really appreciate it. With your table for output the final value in the bottom row of 'current_trade_size' should be 100 though. As no TP has occurred and it is carrying over the previous cells value. maybe removing the cumsum() at this point and replacing with * (1 - (df['take_profit']/100)) would work.